# How do I get variables from JSON when I am receiving this error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, json, api, file-get-contents

So I am using the following source code attempting to retrieve JSON data and parse to PHP string variables:

```
<?php

$jsonfile3 = file_get_contents("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/CME_C1.json");
$jsondata3 = json_decode($jsonfile3);

$cbot_date1 = $jsondata3->dataset->data[0][0];

 echo $cbot_date1; 

 ?>
```

When I use that URL in my browser I can see all of the data. However, when I try to run the script I get the following error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

I've seen similar posts here on stackoverflow but the source code is somewhat different from what I am using so I am slightly confused and would appreciate your help. This same code that I am using has worked fine with other APIs / JSON data sources.

Please let me know any possible solutions that are specific to the source code which I have shown in the above example. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There are probably Apache / PHP settings that prevents you to get remote server data with file_get_contents.

Comment: You need to set `allow_fopen_url` to true in php.ini

Comment: allow_url_fopen is set to "On".  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use php [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) for this.

**Based on you code (un-tested):**

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/CME_C1.json",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Host: www.quandl.com",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if (!$err) {

  $jsondata3 = json_decode($response);

  $cbot_date1 = $jsondata3->dataset->data[0][0];

  echo $cbot_date1; 

} else {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- First initialise curl
- Do a request to the [url](https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/CME_C1.json) you are asking for
- Get the response/error
- Check if there is an error
- If not parse json and display data.

> **Note:** I also noticed that the data you're asking for is 1010.75 KB (little large). And the average request time is 3.41s (little long). It's possible that the curl gives a time out error. That's why I added `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` of 30 seconds.

---

After some testing I concluded that the rate limit for anonymous calls kicks in.

[QELx01](https://docs.quandl.com/docs/error-codes) `429    You have exceeded your daily call limit as an anonymous user.`

I suggest that you get an api key and at this `?api_key=YOURAPIKEY` to the url.

> **Rate limit:** You also commented that you get a white page because there is no curl error, but a rate limit error in the json. Rate limit docs of [Quandl.com](https://docs.quandl.com/docs#section-authentication)

Comment: Getting a white screen when I try this code and can't see anything new in my error log file either :(

Comment: If you add `print_r($jsondata3);` to the next row after the json_decode row. You get the raw response. If I run this I get the following error `You have exceeded the anonymous user limit of 50 calls per day. To make more calls today, please register for a free Quandl account and then include your API key with your requests.`

It seems like a rate limit issue for that dataset.